# Using Attachment field with Classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic, ms-access-2007, attachment-field

I am trying to use attachment datatype in Microsoft access and classical asp to access the database. I am trying to insert attachement from a classical asp form. I got an error "Cannot insert multiple values". I tried a lot online but i cannot find a best fit solution for this. Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, support for the new ACCDB attachment field type has not been included in the ADO object model.  You will need to find a different method to interact with your Access database.  I don't know what method would work and be appropriate for classic ASP.

My inclination would be to revise the database without attachment fields.  That may seem like a painful suggestion to you, but it could be less painful than trying to use attachment fields from classic ASP.